# Unable to make navigation buttons disappear on lg and md views, unable to drop down menu button

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I hope to seek some advice from you guys about the issues I am unable to resolve while coding a simple responsive website.

The navigation buttons should not appear at all and the drop down box should be activated when in xs view.

I am using Twitter bootstrap.

Here is my coding:

```
<nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <a href="index-html"><h1>Food, LLC</h1></a>
            </div>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        </div>

        <div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
       <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a href="chicken.html"><span class="visible-xs"></span>Chicken</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="beef.html"><span class="visible-xs"></span>Beef</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="seafood.html"><span class="visible-xs"></span>Seafood</a>
            </li>
            </ul>
```

The css coding is as follows:

```
body {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #F0FFFF;
    background-color: #778899;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;

#header-nav {
    background-color: #2F4F4F;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 25px;
}
.navbar-brand h1 { /**Restaurant name**/
    font-family: 'Jura', sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-shadow: 1.5px 1.5px #FFD700;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    line-height: 0.5;
}
.navbar-brand a:hover, .navbar-brand a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav-list {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#nav-list a {
    color: #FFFAF0;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav-list a:hover {
    background: #FFD700;
}
#nav-list a span {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Could someone kindly point out where I have gone wrong? Why am I still able to see the navigation buttons at the header? Why doesn't the menu drop down when in xs view?

Thank you, appreciate the help!

Comment: you didn't add any style?

Comment: Yes, I did. I will edit my question post to add them in.

Answer (score 0):

try this working for me

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <a href="index-html"><h1>Food, LLC</h1></a>
            </div>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        </div>

    <div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
   <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            <a href="chicken.html"><span class="visible-xs"></span>Chicken</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="beef.html"><span class="visible-xs"></span>Beef</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="seafood.html"><span class="visible-xs"></span>Seafood</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Amit, thank you for the help. Yes, the dropdown menu works but the navigation buttons still appear when in lg or md views. The script sources also changed the styling of the navigation header.

Comment: which browser you are testing on and please check if you had included any extra css for that and remove that

Comment: I am using Google Chrome. I'm not sure if there are any extra css... I have edited my post to reflect the css coding.

Comment: have you included  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> at starting of code in head section

Comment: ctrl+f5 anr check again

Comment: Yes, I have added the meta. Should I ctrl+f5 on the browser or the code editor? Sorry Amit... I am still a new learner of html, css and javascript... Please bear with me.

Comment: ctrl+f5 on browser

Comment: <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav"> replace this also

Comment: Thanks, Amit... Appreciate the help!